# Changing the text color in bootstrap

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I'm making a navbar in Wordpress with bootstrap. Now I want to change the color of the text. I suppose that is under "a". But I don't know where I need to begin.
Here's my code so far:

```
<nav style="background-color: #C6A970 !important;" class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
  <div class="navbar-header">

    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a>
  </div>

  <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
<?php wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'Main', 'menu_class' => 'nav navbar-nav navbar-left', 'depth'=> 3, 'container'=> false, 'walker'=> new Bootstrap_Walker_Nav_Menu)); ?>
  </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</nav>
```

At the end the code collects the menu items from the menu section in bootstrap. But what section do I need to edit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's behavior depends `navbar-default` class, so you may change it by this way:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
    color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: I configured my child theme well. And this solution works for me! Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking to override the bootstrap template with the following:

```
.navbar .navbar-nav > li > a {
    color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work for me. I think there's something wrong with my child theme css file.